# is it possible to use a class as a return type of a the own method

Tags: c++, class, types, return

Is it possible to use a class as a return type of a class method (ErgbnisAusFortran) like this:

```
class ErgbnisAusFortran
{
public:
   ErgbnisAusFortran();
private:
   int Var_a;
   int Var_b ;  
public: 
   int getVar_a() const { return Var_a; }
   int getVar_res() const { return Var_res; }

   void setVar_res(int input)      {Var_res = input;}
   void setVar_a(int input)        {Var_a = input;}

   ErgbnisAusFortran calculateResults(EingabeWerte Ein);    
};
```

Comment: Yes. Did you try this? What issues did you come across?

Comment: This is absolutely possible and I am sure you are already using such functions in your code (maybe without noticing). For example a `+` operator typically returns a new object of the same class.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse you can use a class as return type. May be you can make a little bit change to your function and you can write like this: `ErgbnisAusFortran calculateResults(const EingabeWerte& Ein);`

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, this is possible. This is also quite common - for example, [*Factory Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern can be implemented within a single class, in which case member functions would be returning instances of the class of which they are members. Another common situation when this is done is immutable classes producing modified versions of themselves.

Although you *can* do it in nearly all situations, there may be situations when you *should not* do it, opting for creating a separate class with a function returning instances of your class. The main criterion is whether it makes sense from a logical point of view.